# How to run Test cases sequentially in cypress?

Tags: cypress

lets take one spec file in cypress in that i have 5 test cases i have to run sequentially

I am tried with npx cypress run command it will run test cases one by one is it write or wrong? i am confused.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is totally normal. Here is a link to the documentation of Cypress, which explains what Parallelization is and how to set it up.
You need to activate parallelization first, in order to use it. However it is not recommended to be done on a singular machine. It needs a significant amount of resources.

[Cypress Parallelization](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/parallelization#What-you-ll-learn)

---

If your project has a large number of tests, it can take a long time for tests to complete running serially on one machine. Running tests in parallel across many virtual machines can save your team time and money when running tests in Continuous Integration (CI).

Cypress can run recorded tests in parallel across multiple machines since version 3.1.0. While parallel tests can also technically run on a single machine, we do not recommend it since this machine would require significant resources to run your tests efficiently.

This guide assumes you already have your project running and recording within Continuous Integration. If you have not set up your project yet, check out our Continuous Integration guide. If you are running or planning to run tests across multiple browsers (Firefox, Chrome, or Edge), we also recommend checking out our Cross Browser Testing guide for helpful CI strategies when using parallelization.

### Turning on parallelization

1. Refer to your CI provider's documentation on how to set up multiple machines to run in your CI environment.
2. Once multiple machines are available within your CI environment, you can pass the [--parallel](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-run-parallel) key to [cypress run](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-run) to have your recorded tests parallelized.

```bash
cypress run --record --key=abc123 --parallel
```

> Running tests in parallel requires the [`--record` flag](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/command-line#cypress-run) be passed. This ensures Cypress can properly collect the data needed to parallelize future runs. This also gives you the full benefit of seeing the results of your parallelized tests in [Cypress Cloud](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/cloud/introduction). If you have not set up your project to record, check out our [setup guide](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/cloud/projects#Setup).

[image: Parallelization]

> Source: Cypress Documentation